# How to uninstall application from iOS when there are many of them?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

How to uninstall some application from iOS?

Please don't say to press and to hold an app icon, because it is impossible to find it visually in my case. My child downloaded a lot of games and made a lot of folders.

I need convenient way to delete application by it's name from alphabetically sorted list.

Is this possible in iOS?

Answer (score 6):

You can plug it into iTunes and delete them from there by pressing uninstall, and apply.

Also, on newer iOS, you can just let iOS offload unused apps. Thirdly, you can now delete apps from settings app.

- settings > general > iPad storage

Answer (score 1):

If you search for the app by name in Spotlight, the name of the folder that contains it will be shown next to the app. Then you can find it in the folder and delete it. See the example here, showing that Pages is in the Writing folder. [image]

Comment: If you find a way to delete a whole folder of apps, we can really break some new ground...  thanks for the visual on another way to locate apps for cleanup. :)